# How to get the minimal absolute value of the differences?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given an array `a[]`, and do the operation `a[i]-x, a[j]+x (x <= a[i])` to two elements of this array for each time. After at most `K` times operation like that, to ensure the value of `max(abs (a[i] - a[j]))` is smallest, and get this smallest value?

My solution: 
Each time, choose two number from this array, and ensure their sum is constant. After K times operation,
we can get the minimal absolute value of the difference of two elements in the array.

However, I do not know whether my idea is correct? if not, how to solve it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your algorithm/question there is no need to make any calculations *during* performing a[i]-x, a[j]+x operations. 
 So my suggestion is:
1) make required number of a[i]-x, a[j]+x operations
2) do the following procedure (in pseudo-code):

```
    _aSorted[] = sort(_a[])
    _dif = max integer value
    for (i=0; i < _a[].length - 1; i++){
      if(abs(_aSorted[i]-_aSorted[i+1]) < _dif)
        _dif = abs(_aSorted[i] -_aSorted[i+1]);
    }
```

So after this procedure `_dif` holds the required result